# Is spark or spark with mesos the easiest to start with?

Tags: apache-spark

If I want a simple setup that would give me a quick start:  would a combination of apache-spark and mesos would be the easiest?  or maybe apache-spark alone would be better because....i.e. mesos would add complexity to the process given what it does, or maybe mesos does way so many things that would be hard to deal with spark alone, etc...

All I want is to be able to submit jobs and manage the cluster and jobs easily, nothing fancy for now, is spark or spark/mesos better or something else...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to start using Spark is starting stand alone spark cluster on EC2.
It is as easy as running single script - [spark-ec2](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ec2-scripts.html) and it will do the rest for you.

The only case when stand alone cluster may not suit you - if you want to run more then single spark job at a time (at least it was the case with Spark 1.1).

For me personally the stand alone Spark cluster was good enough for a long time when I was running ad-hoc jobs - analyzing company's logs on S3 and learning Spark, and then destroy the cluster.

If you want to run more than one Spark at a time - I would go with Mesos.
Alternative would be to install CDH from Cloudera which is relatively easy (they provide install scripts and install instructions) and it is available for free. 
CDH would provide you powerful tools to manage the cluster.

Using CDH for running Spark - they use YARN, and we have one or another issue from time to time with running Spark on YARN.

The main disadvantage to me - CDHs provider its own build of Spark - so it usually one minor version behind, which is a lot for such rapid progressing project as Spark.

So I would try Mesos for running Spark if I need to run more then one job at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, Hortonworks provides downloadable HDP sandbox VM as well as supports Spark on HDP. It is also a good starting point.

Additionally, you can spin off your own cluster. I do thisonmy laptop, not for real big  data usecases but for learning with moderate amount of data.

```
import subprocess as s
from time import sleep
cmd = "D:\\spark\\spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6\\spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6\\spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6\\bin\\spark-class.cmd"

master = "org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master"
worker = "org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker"
masterUrl="spark://BigData:7077"
cmds={"masters":1,"workers":3}

masterProcess=[cmd,master]
workerProcess=[cmd,worker,masterUrl]

noWorker = 3

pMaster = s.Popen(masterProcess)
sleep(3)

pWorkers = []
for i in range(noWorker):
    pw = s.Popen(workerProcess)
    pWorkers.append(pw)
```

The code above starts master and 3 workers, which I can monitor using the UI. This is just to get going and if you need aquick local set up.